# Excel trying to create self organising list

Tags: excel

I have two columns, one is report writer the other is proofreader. I am trying to put together a formula that will automatically assign one of the proofreaders in a list to the report, but if there is a match with the author name then the formula will select the next name in the list. All of my attempts so far have resulted in circular references and errors and i am out of ideas.

Comment: Post few of sample data.

Comment: The data so far is just a list of 5 names. AA, BB, CC ,DD, EE are the initals i have been using with my tests

Comment: So a rand() pick and a logical test to make sure it is not the same. Are all proofreaders equal? if not, then counts to see how many each get, unique() may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worksheetfunction solution is not too sophisticated but works.

The preliminaries

- In Column A the writers
- In Column B the worksheet function (Change C14=5 to the proofreaders count)
- In Column C the random generator formula : **=RANDBETWEEN(1;5)** change 5 to the proofreaders count.
- In Column D the proofreaders

Adjust the formula to the real length for the writers and proofreaders.
After typing the first cell in column B, copy it down till the end row of writers.

The disadvantage that any time you modify a cell automatic recalculation generates new random numbers, so after accepting the pairing copy the range to somewhere with paste special only values.

[image]